# RenderAction differences

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, renderaction

Why is this code correct:

```
 @{
   Html.RenderAction("PostImagesForPost", "BlogPost", new { id = Model.ID });
  }
```

And this code

```
 @Html.RenderAction("PostImagesForPost", "BlogPost", new { id = Model.ID })
```

through this error message:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

Why it is so important to use the '{' '}'?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Html.RenderAction` has to be called within a script block and can't be called in mark-up.

As an alternative in markup you would use:

```
@Html.Action("PostImagesForPost", "BlogPost", new { id = Model.ID })
```

For the differences on `Action` and `RenderAction` see here:

http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx/